# I am unable to install face recognition library

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, pip, face-recognition

I am getting this error. There is more to it.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(517,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]
  Checking Build System
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(517,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ra1cvy6u/dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f/dlib/CMakeLists.txt
  base64_kernel_1.cpp
  bigint_kernel_1.cpp
  bigint_kernel_2.cpp
  bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp
  entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp
  entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp
  entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp
  entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp
  md5_kernel_1.cpp
  tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp
  unicode.cpp
  test_for_odr_violations.cpp
  sockets_kernel_1.cpp
  bsp.cpp
  dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp
  dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp
  dir_nav_extensions.cpp
  fonts.cpp
  linker_kernel_1.cpp
  extra_logger_headers.cpp
  logger_kernel_1.cpp
  logger_config_file.cpp
  misc_api_kernel_1.cpp
  misc_api_kernel_2.cpp
  sockets_extensions.cpp
  sockets_kernel_2.cpp
  sockstreambuf.cpp
  sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp
  server_kernel.cpp
  server_iostream.cpp
  server_http.cpp
  multithreaded_object_extension.cpp
  threaded_object_extension.cpp
  threads_kernel_1.cpp
  threads_kernel_2.cpp
  threads_kernel_shared.cpp
  thread_pool_extension.cpp
  async.cpp
  timer.cpp
  stack_trace.cpp
  cpu_dlib.cpp
  tensor_tools.cpp
  image_dataset_metadata.cpp
  mnist.cpp
  cifar.cpp
  global_function_search.cpp
  kalman_filter.cpp
  auto.cpp
  widgets.cpp
  drawable.cpp
  canvas_drawing.cpp
  style.cpp
  base_widgets.cpp
  gui_core_kernel_1.cpp
  gui_core_kernel_2.cpp
  png_loader.cpp
  save_png.cpp
  jpeg_loader.cpp
  save_jpeg.cpp
  arm_init.c
  filter_neon_intrinsics.c
  png.c
  pngerror.c
  pngget.c
  pngmem.c
  pngpread.c
  pngread.c
  pngrio.c
  pngrtran.c
  pngrutil.c
  pngset.c
  pngtrans.c
  pngwio.c
  pngwrite.c
  pngwtran.c
  pngwutil.c
  adler32.c
  compress.c
  crc32.c
  deflate.c
  gzclose.c
  gzlib.c
  gzread.c
  gzwrite.c
  infback.c
  inffast.c
  inflate.c
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\zlib\gzread.c(319,20): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\zlib\gzwrite.c(212,27): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\zlib\gzwrite.c(232,24): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\zlib\gzread.c(400,35): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\zlib\gzwrite.c(371,36): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\zlib\gzread.c(472,33): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
  inftrees.c
  trees.c
  uncompr.c
  zutil.c
  jaricom.c
  jcapimin.c
  jcapistd.c
  jcarith.c
  jccoefct.c
  jccolor.c
  jcdctmgr.c
  jchuff.c
  jcinit.c
  jcmainct.c
  jcmarker.c
  jcmaster.c
  jcomapi.c
  jcparam.c
  jcprepct.c
  jcsample.c
  jdapimin.c
  jdapistd.c
  jdarith.c
  jdatadst.c
  jdatasrc.c
  jdcoefct.c
  jdcolor.c
  jddctmgr.c
  jdhuff.c
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\libjpeg\jdatadst.c(185,60): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
  jdinput.c
  jdmainct.c
  jdmarker.c
  jdmaster.c
  jdmerge.c
  jdpostct.c
  jdsample.c
  jerror.c
  jfdctflt.c
  jfdctfst.c
  jfdctint.c
  jidctflt.c
  jidctfst.c
  jidctint.c
  jmemmgr.c
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\libjpeg\jerror.c(193,5): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\libjpeg\jerror.c(195,5): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
  jmemnobs.c
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(307,53): warning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(367,70): warning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(977,46): warning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(991,46): warning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(1107,19): warning C4996: 'getenv': This function
```

or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(1110,11): warning C4996: 'sscanf': This function
or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
jquant1.c
jquant2.c
jutils.c
dlib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\dlib_build\Release\dlib19.22.1_release_64bit_msvc1929.lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(517,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
Building Custom Rule C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ra1cvy6u/dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f/tools/python/CMakeLists.txt
dlib.cpp
matrix.cpp
vector.cpp
svm_c_trainer.cpp
svm_rank_trainer.cpp
decision_functions.cpp
other.cpp
basic.cpp
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\basic.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\basic.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\decision_functions.cpp)
[C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\svm_rank_trainer.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\decision_functions.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\svm_rank_trainer.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\matrix.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\matrix.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\other.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\vector.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\dlib.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\other.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\vector.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\dlib.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\svm_c_trainer.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\svm_c_trainer.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern' (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\basic.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern' (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\decision_functions.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern' (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\svm_rank_trainer.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern' (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\matrix.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern' (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\vector.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern' (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\dlib.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern' (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\svm_c_trainer.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern' (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\other.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
cca.cpp
sequence_segmenter.cpp
svm_struct.cpp
image.cpp
image2.cpp
image3.cpp
image4.cpp
rectangles.cpp
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\cca.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\cca.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\sequence_segmenter.cpp)
[C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\sequence_segmenter.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\svm_struct.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\svm_struct.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\image.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\image.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\image2.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\image2.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\image4.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\image4.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\image3.cpp) [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ra1cvy6u\dlib_fbc984c811b2401a9d6e9de52ebc927f\tools\python\src\image3.cpp)

Comment: You should add more detail about a link to the library and anything related to help provide an answer.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of these errors are due to ssize_t being undefined. You can fix this by editing C:\Users\agust\Downloads\dlib-19.22\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h

Find these lines of code near the top of the file after the #include statements:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  pragma warning(push)
#  pragma warning(disable: 4127) // warning C4127: Conditional expression is constant
#endif
```

Change to:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  pragma warning(push)
#  pragma warning(disable: 4127) // warning C4127: Conditional expression is constant
#include <BaseTsd.h>
typedef SSIZE_T ssize_t;
#endif
```

This will provide a definition for ssize_t and allow the compiler to continue
I had this problem too. After the change above, dlib built with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @Horhe & @Dharman's answer above, do make sure that you download the dlib package from the github repository

https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git

After which, navigate to the numpy.h file (As with the above answer) and make the necessary changes to declare ssize_t.

Once that is done, while in the directory of the cloned dlib folder install dlib by typing:

```
python setup.py install
```

This is important as pip install dlib will download the package from elsewhere and the change made to numpy.h in your downloaded folder will not be accessed.

This should install dlib and you can go onto installing face_recognition smoothly by typing:

```
pip install face_recognition
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to https://github.com/datamagic2020/Install-dlib
2. Clone the Repo
3. Extract the zip file
4. Open up the terminal as Administrator
5. Then install the suitable wheel by typing: `pip install \PATH\TO\WHEEL\dlib-19.22.99-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` and making the necessary changes